# I thought I had adequately explained why my question was not a duplicate

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

I asked this question [Should one store a tent loose for prolonged periods between uses to maximize its lifetime?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/15906/should-one-store-a-tent-loose-for-prolonged-periods-between-uses-to-maximize-its).  The first version of my question was, indeed, a duplicate of [What is the best way to store my tent?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/319/what-is-the-best-way-to-store-my-tent).  When this was pointed out, I edited my question (and its title) to explain why the previous question had not adequately addressed my principal concern -- actually, it had not addressed my principal concern at all.

> I am specifically interested in an aspect not covered by that
>   question: does prolonged storage (several years, not several months)
>   in its stuff sack without ever taking it out affect the lifetime of
>   the tent?

Can we reopen my question, or if not, will someone please explain why my question, as edited, still seems like a duplicate to him or her?

Comment: I didn't vote on close or re-open, But your questions seems to use a lot of words to ask if being used at high elevations means you should store it differently the recommended in original.  All the extra words don't add value for me, so I didn't vote.

Comment: @James Jenkins Thanks for replying. I will edit further to make the question shorter.  However, my point is that the original question said nothing, zilch, nada, about storage in stuff stack vs storing loose, nor did any of its answers.  I will clarify why I added a half sentence about UV.

Comment: While it is technically possible for questions to be re-opened after being closed, it is difficult in practice.  Personally, I almost never vote to re-open.  I feel you should get your question right the first time, or be sent home without a cookie.  Consider it punishment for noising up the site with the original question, if that helps.  We don't want people going back and forth experimenting where the limits are.  This isn't a contest to see what you can get away with.  In this case, I didn't look at the original questions and cast no votes.  I'm only explaining my general philosophy.

Comment: @Olin Lathrop "....A contest to see what you can get away with?"  "Noising up the site...."?  Please reconsider those remarks.  I'd better stop now before I say something I will regret

Comment: There is nothing to reconsider.  You asked, and I gave my opinion.  I didn't vote on your questions either way.  In fact, I hadn't looked at them until I saw this meta question, and by that time your second question had already been re-opened.  However, I do take a dim view of someone not posting a good question originally.  It's not much of a problem on this site, but is significant on other SE sites, like Electrical Engineering.  You may not like my opinion, but you did ask for it.

Comment: @Olin Lathrop I did not ask for your opinion on why I revised my question.  It certainly was not because I was in "a contest to see what [I could] get away with", but you are right: I don't like that opinion.

Comment: @OlinLathrop Those comments, especially the first, are very harsh. Both the content, and the fact that they didn't answer what OP was asking, violate SE's [Be Nice](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) policy. I'm posting this for future viewers to see that this type of behavior is not condoned by SE. ab2 correctly followed SE policy when editing the question on the main site, and by bringing the matter here for clarification.

Comment: You really think months versus years would be different methods?